# android how can i force the button row to stay the same size

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

looking at the pictures maybe it's obvious what the problem is.
The button row insist on getting to big in portrait mood.

Remove the

```
android:layout_below="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"
```

then the

`@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity`

checkbox is not visible in landscape mood.

anyone have some ide?

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/topRelativeLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/send_background_color" 

        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/txt1_option_activity"
            android:text = ""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt1_option_activity"
            >
        </TextView>
        <View android:id="@+id/just_a_line_option_activity"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt2_option_activity"
            >
        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/just_a_line_option_activity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_spinner_filesize_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some settings"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt3_option_activity"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_filesize_option_activity"
            >
        </TextView>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_filesize_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt3_option_activity"
            >
        </Spinner>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_spinner_notificationtype_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="some settings"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_filesize_option_activity"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_notificationtype_option_activity"

            >
        </TextView>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_notificationtype_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_filesize_option_activity"

            >
        </Spinner>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_spinner_delay_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="some settings"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_notificationtype_option_activity"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etx_delay_option_activity"

            >
        </TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/etx_delay_option_activity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_notificationtype_option_activity"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="0"
        />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="some settings"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etx_delay_option_activity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            >
        </CheckBox>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linerLayout_send_button_row"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
            android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
            android:paddingTop="5.0dip" 
            android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="1.0dip" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"

            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_send_activity_send_nr_two"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"

            />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_more_activity_send_nr_two"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"

            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your entire `LinearLayout` containing the buttons inside a NEW `RelativeLayout`, placing the `android:layout_below="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"` inside it instead of in the `LinearLayout`:

```
    <!-- the rest of your xml -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linerLayout_send_button_row"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
            android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
            android:paddingTop="5.0dip" 
            android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="1.0dip" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_send_activity_send_nr_two"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"

            />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_more_activity_send_nr_two"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"

            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- the rest of your xml -->
```

Comment: I do not think you need the additional complexity of another relative layout. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the `RelativeLayout`, it should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, NOT `fill_parent`.

Comment: i changed to wrap_content but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for both buttons and delete `android:layout_below="@+id/cb_delete_files_option_activity"` from your linear layout.